# Application to monitor session variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

Is there a third party application or an add-on to monitor session variables for an asp.net application ? When I run my app in development, I would like to monitor session variables as to when they get created, destroyed, change values etc.

Comment: Check out this CodeProject example - not sure if its granular enough for your needs but would be a place to start from perhaps? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4170/Exploring-ASP-NET-Session-State-and-Cache-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at Glimpse? http://getglimpse.com/

"At its core Glimpse allows you to debug your web site or web service right in the browser. Glimpse allows you to "Glimpse" into what's going on in your web server. In other words what Firebug is to debugging your client side code, Glimpse is to debugging your server within the client. " - *from Glimpse website*